# How can we attach alfresco documents to activiti tasks through CMIS in standalone activiti?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, cmis, opencmis

Would it be a good solution to attach the following entities to a task?

- The ID of that particular document
- Link to the document such as
  https://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/content?id=824ba7cd-dcee-4908-8917-7b6ac0611…

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Are you using standalone Activit, or Alfresco Process Services, or the Activiti built into the Alfresco repository?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using standalone version

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Are you wanting to track a reference to an Alfresco document? If so, just use the document's node reference.

Comment: @JeffPotts I am trying to start a process on a document in the same manner that alfresco workflows allow it, but confused on how to do it manually since I can't use the embedded activiti .

Comment: Are you using Enterprise? If so, have you installed and configured the Share Activiti Connector?

Comment: @JeffPotts No, I'm using the community version